# Migrating to Meteor 1.7.0.4 : MongoDB : "updating the path ... would create a conflict at ..."

Tags: mongodb, testing, meteor, mocha.js, conflict

Im using meteor, and im trying to go from meteor 1.6 to 1.7
But im encountering errors im unable to get informations about in my tests :

[tests.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D87HA.png)

I get multiple things like this (some are maybe redondant, unused or obsolete) :

```
Error: Updating the path 'relationChangeRate' would create a conflict at 'relationChangeRate'
at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\fquesselaire\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.0.11\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:45:10)
at toError (C:\Users\fquesselaire\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.0.11\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:149:22)
at C:\Users\fquesselaire\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.0.11\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1029:39
at C:\Users\fquesselaire\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.0.11\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:544:18
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

not occurring in 1.6.*

I tried upgrade my mongodb to 3.6.6, no effect.
Im also unable to get the entire stack in tests to see what is exactly enforcing.

my .meteor/versions :

```
255kb:meteor-status@1.5.0
accounts-base@1.4.2
accounts-password@1.5.1
akasha:fs-extra@0.26.3
alanning:roles@1.2.16
aldeed:autoform@6.3.0
aldeed:autoform-bs-button-group-input@2.0.0
aldeed:autoform-select2@3.0.1
aldeed:collection2-core@2.1.2
aldeed:template-extension@4.1.0
allow-deny@1.1.0
arillo:flow-router-helpers@0.5.2
autoupdate@1.4.1
babel-compiler@7.1.1
babel-runtime@1.2.4
base64@1.0.11
binary-heap@1.0.10
blaze@2.3.2
blaze-html-templates@1.1.2
blaze-tools@1.0.10
boilerplate-generator@1.5.0
caching-compiler@1.1.12
caching-html-compiler@1.1.3
callback-hook@1.1.0
check@1.3.1
coffeescript@1.0.17
cultofcoders:mocha@2.4.6
dburles:collection-helpers@1.1.0
dburles:factory@1.1.0
ddp@1.4.0
ddp-client@2.3.3
ddp-common@1.4.0
ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.7
ddp-server@2.2.0
deps@1.0.12
diff-sequence@1.1.0
dynamic-import@0.4.1
ecmascript@0.11.1
ecmascript-runtime@0.7.0
ecmascript-runtime-client@0.7.2
ecmascript-runtime-server@0.7.1
ejson@1.1.0
email@1.2.3
es5-shim@4.8.0
fourseven:scss@4.9.0
geojson-utils@1.0.10
hot-code-push@1.0.4
html-tools@1.0.11
htmljs@1.0.11
http@1.4.1
id-map@1.1.0
idmontie:migrations@1.0.3
jquery@1.11.11
kadira:blaze-layout@2.3.0
kadira:flow-router@2.12.1
lai:collection-extensions@0.2.1_1
launch-screen@1.1.1
livedata@1.0.18
lmieulet:meteor-coverage@1.1.4
localstorage@1.2.0
logging@1.1.20
matb33:collection-hooks@0.8.4
meteor@1.9.2
meteor-base@1.4.0
meteorhacks:picker@1.0.3
meteortesting:browser-tests@1.0.0
meteortesting:mocha@1.0.0
minifier-css@1.3.1
minifier-js@2.3.5
minimongo@1.4.4
mobile-experience@1.0.5
mobile-status-bar@1.0.14
modern-browsers@0.1.2
modules@0.12.2
modules-runtime@0.10.2
momentjs:moment@2.22.2
mongo@1.5.1
mongo-dev-server@1.1.0
mongo-id@1.0.7
mouse0270:bootstrap-notify@3.1.3
natestrauser:select2@4.0.3
npm-bcrypt@0.9.3
npm-mongo@3.0.11
observe-sequence@1.0.16
ordered-dict@1.1.0
ostrio:cookies@2.3.0
ostrio:files@1.10.1
practicalmeteor:chai@2.1.0_1
practicalmeteor:loglevel@1.2.0_2
practicalmeteor:mocha-core@1.0.1
practicalmeteor:sinon@1.14.1_2
promise@0.11.1
raix:eventemitter@0.1.3
random@1.1.0
rate-limit@1.0.9
reactive-dict@1.2.1
reactive-var@1.0.11
reload@1.2.0
retry@1.1.0
rocketchat:streamer@0.5.0
routepolicy@1.0.13
service-configuration@1.0.11
session@1.1.8
sewdn:collection-behaviours@0.3.0
sha@1.0.9
shell-server@0.3.1
socket-stream-client@0.2.2
softwarerero:accounts-t9n@1.3.11
spacebars@1.0.15
spacebars-compiler@1.1.3
srp@1.0.12
standard-minifier-css@1.4.1
standard-minifier-js@2.3.4
templating@1.3.2
templating-compiler@1.3.3
templating-runtime@1.3.2
templating-tools@1.1.2
tmeasday:check-npm-versions@0.3.2
tmeasday:test-reporter-helpers@0.2.1
tracker@1.2.0
ui@1.0.13
underscore@1.0.10
url@1.2.0
useraccounts:bootstrap@1.14.2
useraccounts:core@1.14.2
useraccounts:flow-routing@1.14.2
webapp@1.6.2
webapp-hashing@1.0.9
zimme:active-route@2.3.2
```

my node packages :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.54",
    "@mdi/font": "^2.5.94",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^0.5.10",
    "bootstrap-slider": "^10.0.2",
    "bootstrap-toggle": "^2.2.2",
    "clone": "^2.1.1",
    "csv-parse": "^2.5.0",
    "d3": "^5.5.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "fs-extra": "^3.0.1",
    "gm": "^1.23.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "jsondiffpatch": "^0.3.11",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "select2": "^4.0.4",
    "select2-bootstrap-theme": "^0.1.0-beta.10",
    "simpl-schema": "^1.5.3",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "xmldoc": "^1.1.0",
    "zip-local": "^0.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.40.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^3.6.0"
  }
```

if you have any clue about what is going on ?
i can give more informations about what's happening in the app, but right now a simple explain about what this error mean would be awesome already. as i said, this error only append in 1.7.

EDIT: forget to say that my test throw this on WORKING code.
Features are working well, but not the tests.

EDIT²:

This method is the one that update the collection projectSettings.

```
_duplicateProjectSettings(newSession) {
  const settings = this.session.projectSettings();
  delete settings._id;
  settings.sessionId = newSession._id;
  const newSettings = newSession.projectSettings();
  ProjectSettings.update(newSettings._id, { $set: settings });
}
```

relationChangeRate is a simpl-schema field of projectSettings collection as it (i use collection2-core) :

```
relationChangeRate: {
  type: Number,
  allowedValues: _.values(RelationRates),
  defaultValue: 0.0
}
```

projectSettings extends mongo.collection, but in this case, update method is not override.
The code seams correct to me, as the _id is well removed and set to the new object before update request. but maybe im wrong ?

EDIT³:

ProjectSettings is a [collection-helper](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/collection-helpers):

Here is the code :

```
Sessions.helpers({
[...]
  projectSettings() {
      const conds = { sessionId: this._id };
      return ProjectSettings.findOne(conds);
  },
[...]
```

A collection helper basically add a method on each document from this collection. It means that any session object will have this method. In a collection helper, "this" refer to the current collection object.

so should  be good ?

_duplicateProjectSettings could be write like this:

```
_duplicateProjectSettings(newSession) {
  // const settings = this.session.projectSettings();
  const settings = ProjectSettings.findOne({ sessionId: this.session._id });
  delete settings._id;
  settings.sessionId = newSession._id;
  // const newSettings = newSession.projectSettings();
  const newSettings = ProjectSettings.findOne({ sessionId: newSession._id });
  ProjectSettings.update(newSettings._id, { $set: settings });
}
```

(I tried it too, same result)

Comment: Are you updating/upserting the `relationChangeRate` somewhere? Is it possible that you are either targeting it multiple times in your update clause (e.g, `$set` and `$inc`) or upsert (e.g, `$set` and `$setOnInsert`)? Are you using `findAndModify`?

Comment: Actually yes.

there is a function called duplicate that create a copy on an object in the base.
in the same function,

I call `Session.create` (that is an overload, calling `ProjectSettings.create`)
Because Session object depend of ProjectSettings.

Then, in the following of the code, ProjectSettings is Updated.

What should append before i can update ProjectSettings ?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what is going on there. Those sound like distinct queries that shouldn't affect each other (at least in terms of this error message). Can you edit your question to include the relevant query/queries that updates the `relationChangeRate` field? I am looking specifically for such queries that have multiple clauses, where more than one target that field.

Comment: i edited the post as you asked, please, let me know if you need more informations.

Comment: Well, technically this is the code, but it's unclear what is the actual object that's being transferred to the `update` query. However, it does not seem likely that it is the cause. Are there any other queries that involve this field? You can try to pinpoint the cause by logging or commenting out some of the queries. Setting the compatibility mode might help with getting rid of the error, but if your production server will be set differently, you may encounter them in production.

Comment: ProjectSettings() is a collection Helper made with https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/collection-helpers
I will edit my post to add details.

Comment: Added a github bug ticket at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10168

Answer (score 1):

Running this from shell worked for me... not the best solution. I had the problem when I tried to login with accounts-password package.

```
$ meteor mongo
meteor:PRIMARY> db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
```

Comment: unfortunately, i will not be able to test it before mounday the 20th.
Anyway thanks for your answer.
Even if the solution is not ideal, it is better than nothing.
Im using accounts-password package too. Maybe related ?

Comment: I tried this solution,
As im using external Mongo database, i launched mongo executable from my local mongo installation folder, (by default C:\Program files\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin)
then i launched a cmd from this path, and entered this command.

Comment: got {"ok": 1} in return
Restarted Mongo service, restarted my meteor tasks, no effect, my tests keep throwing,

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

This is an half-answer but
After some extended search i figured that i had a test script that reset MONGO_URL as follow :

```
set MONGO_URL=
set TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=chrome
set TEST_WATCH=1
set TEST_CLIENT=0
set TEST_SERVER=1

meteor test -p 3100 --driver-package=cultofcoders:mocha %*
```

after figuring that i launched the tests on my local dev db, and tests passed (smashing my db by the way lol). So, it means it could be version related, or test-conditions related.
I am not able to print the version of mongodb used for tests, so i don't know the tests conditions exactly.

All i know is so :
Meteor "normal run" Mongo version : 3.6.4
My local Mongo version : 3.6.6